Is there any property in Linear Algebra if a single element equals 0?
Consider the Matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & 0\\
e & f & g & h\\
i & j & k & l\\
l & m & n & o
\end{bmatrix}$$
where all the letters $a$ through $o$ are supposed to represent constants in $\mathbb{R}$. Is there any property that says we can now evaluate the determinant of this matrix by completely excluding the row and the column that the $0$ is in? In other words, can we calculate the determinant of this matrix without $a$, $b$, $c$, $h$, $l$, and $o$ in consideration? I feel like I remember there was some property in Linear Algebra, but I don't know if I am just misremembering or getting this mixed up with another property. If there is a property that says we can do this, can we extend it to $\mathbb{C}$?
Thank You!

No. Consider any diagonal matrix.

So, there is no property like this in Linear Algebra? Yes or no? @BenSteffan

Read the first word of my comment above, and think about counterexamples.

Did you perchance try the $2\times 2$ case?

Yeah, I now know that with the use of counterexample, that the answer is indeed no. I just remember some property in Linear Algebra that was very similar to this. Hmmm ... I'll have to dig then.

Perhaps what you're remembering is the Laplace expansion of the determinant along a row or column.  So e.g. your determinant is  the sum of the entries in the top row times $(+/-)$ the $3 \times 3$ determinants of the matrices obtained by deleting the row and column of those entries.  In the case of an entry of $0$, of course you don't need to compute the $3 \times 3$ determinant.  But this shows exactly how the determinant depends on any individual entry.

And by the way, since the determinant is a polynomial in the matrix entries with integer coefficients, the same formulas that work for $\mathbb R$ also work for $\mathbb C$ (or any other field, for that matter).
